# AngularJS: Loading animation timing

Tags: angularjs, loading, servicenow

Our team is developing a widget in ServiceNow and want to show a loading symbol in our Submit button.  We've gotten it to show up, but the loading symbol lasts for several seconds after the table has already loaded and we're not sure why.  Here is what our widget currently looks like:

```
<form class="large-margin-bottom col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="Name Text">${Full Name}:</label>
   <input class="input-lg form-control" type="text" ng-model= "c.data.fullName" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" >
  </div>

  <button type="submit" ng-click="c.send_fullName();"class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    <i ng-if="c.data.loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin m-r-sm"></i>${Search}
  </button>
</form>


 <div ng-if= "data.showTable == 'hi' && !c.data.loading">  
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <caption>List of actions for this Employee</caption>
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Occupation</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data.json">
      <td>{{item.name_employee_full}}</td>
      <td>{{item.occ}}</td>
      <td>{{item.loc}}</td>
      <td>{{item.start}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Our Client Controller looks like this:

```
function($scope, $location) {
    /* widget controller */
    var c = this;

    //Name send to server
    c.send_fullName = function() {
        c.data.loading = true;
        c.data.action = "addName";
        c.data.loading = false;
        c.server.update().then(function(){
            c.data.action = undefined;
            c.data.fullName= '';
        })
    }
}
```

Our Server Script looks like this:

```
(function() {

data.fullName= '';
data.showTable = '';
data.json = [];

    if (input){
        data.fullName = input.fullName;
        var subject_person = fetchHR(data.fullName);
        data.json = getEmployeeData(data.fullName);


        if (input.action == 'addName'){
            data.showTable = "hi" ;
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with using this combined with input and server.update():

HTML

```
<div class="loader" ng-show="loadingIndicator">
  <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Client Script

```
//loading spinner icon
$scope.loadingIndicator = $rootScope.loadingIndicator;
$scope.$on('sp_loading_indicator', function(e, value) {
    $scope.loadingIndicator = value;
});
```

CSS

```
.loader {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin: 50px 0;
}
.spinner-border{
//from bootstrap 4.4:
display: inline-block;
width: 3rem;
height: 3rem;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
border: .25em solid currentColor;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
color: #cccccc;
}
@keyframes spinner-border{
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```